# Would you please let me know what dry rust is?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I know what means **rust** and also what means **dry**.

From the context I think it is some substance which coats a surface and acts like a rust inhibitor for a rust protection purpose.

Here is the context:

> High corrosion resistance of the cast iron boilers due to application of the **dry rust** to prevent expansion of corrosion.

I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: are you missing *is* there? Or am I missing something ;)

Comment: @Maulik V, it’s listed as a feature (advantage) without predicate.

Comment: I think this is a typo. You can't "apply" rust, which is the result of a chemical process; I think a word has been dropped, probably "application of a dry rust **inhibitor**".

Comment: @StoneyB, I thought the same as you firstly. Reading Josh61’s answer and comments I have started to wonder: What if it is naturally produced and applied (it’s not wet, it’s dry rust). What do you think?
On the other hand, I have the file from a Russian manufacturer and there might be mistakes if they didn’t employ a native to make the text.

Comment: @LucianSava I speak under correction by a chemist or engineer; but rust is rust, and I see no reason to think that the inhibitive effect of dry rust would be greater than that of wet rust. In any case, I don't think you can **apply** rust except by mixing it into a binder like paint, and in that case it would be the paint that provides the resistance. Finally, Google "dry rust"--you'll find most of the hits are for "dry rust inhibitor" or "preventive".

Comment: @StoneyB, thank you very much! I've got now what nonsense is written on that sheet.

Comment: Some of the articles ("the") in that sentence are incorrect. That sentence does not appear to have been written by a native speaker. They probably translated "dry rust" from their native language incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rust** is a form of corrosion, **a dry rust**  forms mainly through the presence of gases in the air.

Comment: So it’s producing itself like ordinary rust isn’t it? And once produced it prevents further rust penetration in the body, right? It is not a factory made product, right?

Comment: It is the result of corrosion trough a dry process , not a wet one.